# How can I run a script via bluetooth and issue commands?

Tags: debian, bluetooth, serial-port, bluez

I am fairly new to Linux and I am trying to use beaglebone black (debian) to try and run a script via bluetooth that will allow me to issue some simple commands and have the board do stuff. I am able to connect to the board via bluetooth and send messages with a bluetooth serial app on my android phone or on my windows laptaop but its nothing more than a string of characters. If I try to issue a command it doesn't work the way it does when I issue one via SSH with putty.

I am using this book and it doesnt have much info about bluetooth beyond this: [https://www.amazon.com/Exploring-BeagleBone-Techniques-Building-Embedded/dp/1119533163](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119533163)

I installed bluez version 5.50

```
sudo apt install bluetooth bluez
```

Then I went into /lib/systemd/system and issued command

```
more bluetooth.service
```

While there I modified the bluetooth.service file by adding      "--compat" to the end of the line that has *ExecStart=/usr/lib/blueooth/bluetoothd **--compat***

Then I exited and restarted bluetooth with

```
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth.service
```

Now I changed bluetooth serial port to channel 22

```
sudo sdptool add --channel=22 SP
```

lastly, I set the bluetooth adapter to listen with

```
sudo rfcomm listen /dev/rfcomm0 22
```

After that I can use the bluetooth serial app to connect by keeping the current putty ssh open (it will show that there is bluetooth connection) and I can open up another SSH with putty and if I issue command

```
cat /dev/rfcomm0
```

the new terminal window will display everything I send from the serial app. It's my understanding of this process so far that anything sent by the app just goes into rfcomm0 and is displayed, meaning commands wont do anything or go anywhere to run something. The book also says you can install minicom but it won't work for me.

Ultimately I would like to have a python script on the board that I can run and issue commands to from my laptop via bluetooth, is there a way to change where character strings I send from app go? or have a SSH over bluetooth so that they can be executed?